ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
I've tried several solutions I found in similar questions, but none of them have worked for me. That's why I'm asking this as a new question.
After upgrading to hibernate 5 e jpa 2 I get the following error at runtime when I try to start my jboss server:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
bean with name org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': 
Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean] 
from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader 
for Module "deployment.sfv-webapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.2
This is my pom file:
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
               <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
               <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
               <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
               <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
           </dependency>
               <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
               <version>${spring.version}</version>
               <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                       <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
               <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
               <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
               <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
           </dependency>


It seems I have all the required dependency but I think there is some conflict between versions of my jars. Can someone help me?
EDIT: This is a legacy project, it will reach end of life in few months, is mandatory use hibernate 5.4.12 and javax (no jakarta)

By the way, Hibernate 5.4 is end-of-life. See Releases page. Ditto for Hibernate Validator 5.4. See Releases page.

For business reason I need to use Hibernate 5.4, the end of life is not a problem, in few months this projects will be discarded. Still I can't solve my problem

If you're running in JBoss EAP 6.2 you should mark all the Hibernate dependencies as <scope>provided</scope> as they're provided by the container. Same with the javax.validation:validation-api.

@JamesR.Perkins is not enough in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file define in exlusions tag



?

Ah, is there a reason for that? They're already provided, why not use them?

@JamesR.Perkins in the moduled folder, I see is present the artifact validation-api-1.0.0-GA-redhat-2. The javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider method was added in version 1.1, so I believe it's not present in the artifact provided by JBoss. What do you think?

@JamesR.Perkins i'm upgrading the server to JBoss EAP 7.2, you know what I need to change to let it work?

JBoss EAP 7.2 is a Java EE 8 server so ti should contain the newer version of validation.  Typically you should rely on the dependencies provided by the server and not include them in your deployment.

@JamesR.Perkins thanks for the reply, so your saying I don't need the javax.validation and hibernate validator as dependency in my pom, and I should not exclude them in the jboss structure deployment, right?

@coman You need a copy of the API while developing but not at deployment. The compiler does not know about Jakarta Validation; you teach the compiler about Jakarta Validation by having a copy available in your project. But you do not want that copy in your final software artifact (likely a WAR file). At runtime your Jakarta server implementation (JBoss in your case) comes with (A) a copy of the Jakarta APIs including Jakarta Validation, and (B) a copy of an implementation of the API (Hibernate Validator). Learn about scope in POM.

See Maven guide to scope in POM. See article at Baeldung.com. See article at Payara.

You will likely need the API JAR on your compile class path as @BasilBourque says. You'd just mark the dependency as <scope>provided</scope>.

@JamesR.Perkins I understand better what you mean now, I'm just still confused about excluding this dependency or not in the jboss-structure-deployment file.

JBoss implements the “full” platform profile of Jakarta EE. Jakarta Validation is a required part of the “full” platform profile of Jakarta EE. Therefore JBoss comes bundled with the Jakarta Validation API (interfaces). And JBoss comes bundled with an implementation of the Jakarta Validation spec & API. You should not include either in your final software artifact (WAR file likely) asJBoss provides them at runtime. But you must have the API (interfaces) present while developing so the compile can make sense of your code that calls upon Jakarta Validation. Now read the links I gave you.

I did, but why in other posts and some old colleagues have excluded this dependency in the jboss structure xml file?? I cannot understand this!

I know nothing about “jboss structure xml”. But I do know that your posted POM is including both the API for, and an implementation of, Jakarta Validation in your final software artifact. You do not want that. JBoss provides both.

So it will be (i deleted the validator)

org.hibernate
hibernate-core
5.4.12.Final


javax.validation
validation-api
2.0.1.Final
provided


Good. You may not even need that if Spring provides the Validation API. I don’t know, because I don’t use Spring.

Thank you. Last question, do you know if I need this too:

javax.el
javax.el-api
3.0.0
provided

? or something like that?

Same story. If the API is provided by Spring, then no. If not, yes. AFAIK Jakarta Expression Language is a required part of the ”full” profile of Jakarta EE. Therefore JBoss includes both the API and an implementation. You really should learn more about the tools you are using rather than stumbling about blindly pasting snippets into a POM while crossing your fingers.

Thanks god jboss is death technology :)
